# How can I hide a list item element that is buried in my website?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to hide this list item on our new website as it currently isn't natively possible.

[Screenshot of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5akGZ.png)

Is there an easy way to make this hidden?

Thank you

Comment: Please see [ask]. We don't debug images here.

Comment: When you revise to improve the question, be sure to explain _why_ that element is the one you're targeting. What's special about it in the context of your page? Don't make us guess.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to be careful that you aren't ruining other lists that might be in your page so I'd be as specific as I could be on this one:

```
.container > .navbar > .navbar-section .navbar-item:nth-child(2) { display: none; }
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you and will try it out.

Comment: For what it is worth, this one helped and I was able to solve my issue thanks to your suggestion. Appreciate it A Haworth!

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way to hide element is to do smth like this

```
    li:nth-child(2) {
      display: none;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't write in text-speak on SO. "smth" isn't a word.

Comment: And if you need clarification, comment on the _question_, not on your answer.

Comment: Thank you Aaron, I will try. I do appreciate and can understand what you mean. gg

Answer (score -1):

I think Use one of these:

```
display: none;  #The item disappears without leaving any traces
```

or

```
visibility: hidden; #The item disappears while retaining its place
```

see the difference her:
[What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)